# How to refresh page every 2 seconds?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I wanna to setup a web messenger. So I want to reload my page every 1 or 2 seconds. Actually I want a silent reload to get new chats from my database. Most methods just reload page and clear all inputs. Please help me.

I tried:
`function loadlink(){     $('#links').load('test.php',function () {          $(this).unwrap();     }); } loadlink(); setInterval(function(){     loadlink() }, 5000);`

And:
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2">`

Comment: You should look into websockets.

Comment: Try long-polling or websockets.

Comment: Refresh will clear everything and reload the page.  What you need to use are ajax calls.  Using these you can load the new messages only and add to the display.

Comment: Thats difficult.  Either you need to use something slightly higher level like python, or study these examples, start small and get ajax working.  Then integrate it to your project. [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_examples.asp) and [tutorial](https://www.studentstutorial.com/ajax/introduction).  If you get stuck, then post another question with that code.

Comment: To build on what RohitGupta had said - since you seem to be using jQuery, you should also take a look at their [official documentaiton](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

This tag refreshes the whole page, not ideal:

> meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2"

[Here](https://codeshack.io/live-support-chat-ajax-php-mysql/) I found a complete article about this.

It uses php, MySql (to store chat and authentication) and vanilla js ajax calls to refresh chat.

As others stated executing ajax requests every 2 seconds might slow down your server. Better to try with 3-5 secs.

This example uses 5 seconds.
It is set by setInterval(), using milliseconds. 5000ms = 5 sec.

Here is the ajax part that updates conversations (copied from the example):

```
setInterval(() => {
    // If the current tab is 2
    if (currentChatTab == 2) {
        // Use AJAX to update the conversations list
        fetch('conversations.php', { cache: 'no-store' }).then(response => response.text()).then(html => {
            let doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
            document.querySelector('.chat-widget-conversations').innerHTML = doc.querySelector('.chat-widget-conversations').innerHTML;
            conversationHandler();
        }); 
    // If the current tab is 3 and the conversation ID variable is not NUll               
    } else if (currentChatTab == 3 && conversationId != null) {
        // Use AJAX to update the conversation
        fetch('conversation.php?id=' + conversationId, { cache: 'no-store' }).then(response => response.text()).then(html => {
            // The following variable will prevent the messages container from automatically scrolling to the bottom if the user previously scrolled up in the chat list
            let canScroll = true;
            if (document.querySelector('.chat-widget-messages').lastElementChild && document.querySelector('.chat-widget-messages').scrollHeight - document.querySelector('.chat-widget-messages').scrollTop != document.querySelector('.chat-widget-messages').clientHeight) {
                canScroll = false;
            }                    
            let doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
            // Update content
            document.querySelector('.chat-widget-messages').innerHTML = doc.querySelector('.chat-widget-messages').innerHTML;
            if (canScroll && document.querySelector('.chat-widget-messages').lastElementChild) {
                // Scroll to the bottom of the container
                document.querySelector('.chat-widget-messages').scrollTop = document.querySelector('.chat-widget-messages').lastElementChild.offsetTop;
            }                   
        });  
    // If the current tab is 3 and the status is Waiting           
    } else if (currentChatTab == 3 && status == 'Waiting') {
        // Attempt to find a new conversation between the user and operator (or vice-versa)
        fetch('find_conversation.php', { cache: 'no-store' }).then(response => response.text()).then(data => {
            if (data != 'error') {
                // Success! Two users are now connected! Retrieve the new conversation
                getConversation(data);
            }
        });               
    }
}, 5000); // 5 seconds (5000ms) - the lower the number, the more demanding it is on your server.
```

Note: it has many more parts as well, the ajax call is only a small slice of the cake.

Answer (score -1):

Refreshing your whole page every 2 seconds is not an excellent idea.
You should read more on `WebSockets` or use `ajax`